# Redirect image request

Tags: httpwebrequest, background-image, asp.net-mvc

i have used the background image css in our wesite.

```
.banner-image{
   height: 76%;
   background-image: url("http://cdn.images.com/contents/images/home/bannerimage.PNG");
}
```

if i run www.test.com, this page background has the bannerimage.i am requesting the banner image from cdn domain. there i have uploaded the images.

Here i need to handle the case, that browser send the image request to cdn.images.com server and get the response. If the images doesn't exist in cdn, i need to handle it by send the request to our local server "www.test.com" where i have placed duplicates of the all required images.

how can i do this? can we use image handler for this? if yes how?

Could anyone please give me the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="/">
        <span class="header-title">My gray sea design</span><br />
        <span class="header-title-two">A beautiful design</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.header a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://www.xyz.com/images/embouchure.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:160px;
    padding-left:280px;
    padding-top:50px;
    width:470px;
    color: #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: :can you please explain your answer clearly? I couldn't get your answer.